# How to get last SQL replication error when multithreading is enabled?

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

Since MySQL 8.0.27, multithreading is now enabled by default for replica servers. [Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-27.html)

Until then, if the replication failed, we could get the exact error from `Last_Error` in the result of `show replica status\G;`. Now, the query is replaced by "Anonymous":

> Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s). The
> most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed executing transaction
> 'ANONYMOUS' at master log mysql-bin.031116, end_log_pos 81744270. See
> error log and/or
> performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more
> details about this failure or others, if any.

The table `performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker` does not contain the exact error either:

```
mysql> select * from performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                                           CHANNEL_NAME:
                                              WORKER_ID: 1
                                              THREAD_ID: 128
                                          SERVICE_STATE: ON
                                      LAST_ERROR_NUMBER: 0
                                     LAST_ERROR_MESSAGE:
                                   LAST_ERROR_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
                               LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION: ANONYMOUS
     LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_ORIGINAL_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 2021-11-16 11:35:04.414021
    LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_IMMEDIATE_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 2021-11-16 11:35:04.414021
         LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_START_APPLY_TIMESTAMP: 2021-11-16 11:35:04.416898
           LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_END_APPLY_TIMESTAMP: 2021-11-16 11:35:04.420018
                                   APPLYING_TRANSACTION:
         APPLYING_TRANSACTION_ORIGINAL_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
        APPLYING_TRANSACTION_IMMEDIATE_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
             APPLYING_TRANSACTION_START_APPLY_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
                 LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_RETRIES_COUNT: 0
   LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_NUMBER: 0
  LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_MESSAGE:
LAST_APPLIED_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000
                     APPLYING_TRANSACTION_RETRIES_COUNT: 0
       APPLYING_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_NUMBER: 0
      APPLYING_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_MESSAGE:
    APPLYING_TRANSACTION_LAST_TRANSIENT_ERROR_TIMESTAMP: 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000

-- <I've removed 3 other similar blocks>
```

I can indeed find the error in the MySQL error log (e.g. `"Could not execute Write_rows event on table db.table; Duplicate entry '16737' for key 'table.PRIMARY'"`), but not from a query anymore.

Is there another query that would give me this last error message? Or a specific setting to log it & display it under `show replica status\G;`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are correct. Based on the documentation, once you are using **MTR (multi-threaded replication)**, the SQL thread is the coordinator for worker threads. Here’s what the documentation has to say about it:

> If the replica is multithreaded, the SQL thread is the coordinator for worker threads. In this case, the `Last_SQL_Error` field shows exactly what the `Last_Error_Message` column in the Performance Schema `replication_applier_status_by_coordinator` table shows. The field value is modified to suggest that there may be more failures in the other worker threads which can be seen in the `replication_applier_status_by_worker` table that shows each worker thread's status. If that table is not available, the replica error log can be used. The log or the `replication_applier_status_by_worker` table should also be used to learn more about the failure shown by `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` or the coordinator table.

In that case, you can check with the `performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_coordinator` then know more via `performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker` . Otherwise, error log can be used.